# How to redirect a domain to another one on my machine only?

Tags: dns, hosts, hostname

I want all requests from my machine to

```
example.com
```

be redirected to

```
example.com.edgesuite.net
```

I tried adding the following line to the `hosts` file both on Windows and Linux

```
example.com.edgesuite.net        example.com
```

but the `nslookup` still resolves to the old IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosts file expects an IP address for each hostname listed.

You may need to look up the IP address of `example.com.edgesuite.net` and use it in the hosts file.

First perform the DNS lookup:

```
C:\>nslookup example.com.edgesuite.net
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    a1081.b.akamai.net
Addresses:  24.143.196.115, 24.143.196.123
Aliases:  example.com.edgesuite.net
```

Then add a line line in your hosts file such as:

```
24.143.196.115 example.com
```

or

```
24.143.196.123 example.com
```

But keep in mind that if `example.com.edgesuite.net` ever changes its IP address, then you will have to make a corresponding change in your hosts file.

Comment: it worked for pings but my nslookup still resolves for the old IP

Comment: @Jader Dias: do an ipconfig /flushdns and give it another try.  That'll flush your resolver cache, maybe you've got the old records still stuck in the cache.

Comment: I tried it too, but it didn't work. Maybe nslookup doesn't looks into the hosts file (try nslookup localhost).

Comment: If you want `nslookup` to behave as described in the above comments, then consider running your own DNS server and pointing your client(s) to that DNS server, such as http://www.powerdns.com/ PowerDNS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar need for my local environment (localhost). 
I use Firefox browser and installed the addon called "[Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/)". Very basic and easy configuration (it took me less than 5 minutes to get the first redirection working). Thanks to Einar Egilsson!

In case you are wondering about settings:

```
Description: Anything

Example URL: https://example.com/

Include pattern: https://example.com/*

Redirect to: http://example.com.edgesuite.net/$1

Pattern type:  Wildcard

Apply to: (checked all)
```